# How To Bind a Button inside a DataTemplate to a Window's Viewmodel Command?

Tags: wpf, binding, datatemplate

I have a funny problem with `Binding`,I have a `DataTemplate` that contain a `Button`,and the `DataTemplate` had been placed in a Window(specView),i need to bind the `Button.Command` to a `Commnad` inside window's viewmodel,so i do this:

```
Command="{Binding DataContext.NewOfferNoCommand,ElementName=specView}"/>
```

but it doesn't get bound until i make a Converter that return the value:

```
public class ReturnValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

I really can't understand what the problem is?any idia?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the relative source in order for the binding to work.

```
{Binding DataContext.NewOfferNoCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}
```